How to change the Album example in Flutter to a list of Albums
I am fairly new to Flutter and am converting a React Native app to Flutter. I am struggling with an example from the flutter documentation to read a json file from the cloud.
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data
In my application, I want to read a list of "Albums" like in the example code. But it seems no matter what I try, I run into different errors. This is the closest I have come to get it working. Basically it is identical to the Album example except that I make it a List of Albums, I use my JSON file and my class for decoding the JSON.
When I run it, on line 96 List<Future<EngagementText>> futureAlbum = []; I get:

Exception has occurred.
RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)

I have tried many things and continue to get different errors based on all the different approaches I have taken.
Here is the code:
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
// Used my class instead of album
Future<EngagementText> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      'https://ListeningToGod.org/SermonEngagement/TextFiles/2024-09-0801a.json'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return EngagementText.fromJson(
        jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>);
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

 
// *** USED my class instead of album
class EngagementText {
  String? version;
  String? date;
  String? text;
  List<Links>? links;

  EngagementText({this.version, this.date, this.text, this.links});

  EngagementText.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    try {
      version = json['version'];
      date = json['date'];
      text = json['text'];
      if (json['links'] != null) {
        links = <Links>[];
        json['links'].forEach((v) {
          links!.add(Links.fromJson(v));
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      date = "2024-01-01";
      text = "Dummy Text";
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['version'] = version;
    data['date'] = date;
    data['text'] = text;
    if (links != null) {
      data['links'] = links!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Links {
  String? link;
  String? text;

  Links({this.link, this.text});

  Links.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    link = json['link'];
    text = json['text'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['link'] = link;
    data['text'] = text;
    return data;
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  //late Future<EngagementText> futureAlbumText;
  List<Future<EngagementText>> futureAlbum = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
      futureAlbum[index] = fetchAlbum();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<EngagementText>(
            future: futureAlbum[3],  // referenced the array instead
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data!.text as String);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Try this futureAlbum.add(fetchAlbum()); instead of futureAlbum[index] = fetchAlbum(); or if you want to use still index use futureAlbun.insert(index, fetchAlbum());

Yes - "add" works as does "insert." THANK YOU! I have to use insert because of the way I am using it. I would never have guessed this. Do you or anyone know why [] is not defined the way I tried to use it? Is there another way for me to do that? Where does the documentation tell me that it is not defined? I am an old C programmer - getting my first C compiler from Bell Labs in 1976. I prefer my Dart code to look more C like.

because in c you can access via [] because you don't declare empty arrays usually...  that's why you can always access it on certain index. While in dart you can't try to access and assign via [] if there's no element at specified index. After you insert an element you can read it and change it via [index] but before you have to populate that array via declaration or via .add or .insert methods

just added it as an answer

In dart you can't access and assign via [] brackets if there's no element at specified index. After you insert an element you can read it and change it via [index] but before you have to populate that array into declaration (assignment) or via .add or .insert methods

futureAlbum.add(fetchAlbum());

///or if you are pretty sure of what you are doing...

futureAlbum.insert(index, fetchAlbum());


